# Angular 9 file upload not adding file to formgroup

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

I have created a form group in my HTML for an Angular 9 application. In this form group, there is an upload feature for a file. The upload is working correctly when the handleFileInput function is called, which I can see through the console log under it. However, the file property is still NULL when I send the form group to my service. I understand that this is due to it being set as NULL in my constructor, but how can I change my code so that the file in the form group is set to the file uploaded? From what I have read the form group must be declared in the constructor.

```
export class HelpComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  srcPage = 'Test';
  fileToUpload: File = null;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private messageService: MessageService,
              public exportFilesService: ExportFilesService) {

  this.form = this.fb.group({
        summary: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        description: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        isurgent: [false],
        file: this.fileToUpload
      });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    console.log(this.fileToUpload);
  }

  submitForm() {
      this.messageService.sendSupportRequest(this.form.get('summary').value , 
      this.form.get('description').value, this.form.get('isurgent').value, 
      this.srcPage, this.form.get('file').value);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, file uploading is not handled by Angular explicitly or by ReactiveForms like this.

To have file upload thing, you could do something like this:
in `html` file:

```
<input type="file" (change)="handleFile($event)" />
```

And in `ts`:

```
handleFile(event) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();

        const files=event.target.files;
        files.foreach(file=>{
            formData.append(file);
        })

        this.form.patchValue({file:formData});
        this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
```

Second,The FormBuilder `fb` being assigned to your FormGroup `form` should be done inside `ngOnInit()` function.

Which should look like this:

```
form:FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
this.form = this.fb.group({
        summary: new ['', [Validators.required]],
        description: ['', [Validators.required]],
        isurgent: [false],
        file: ['']
      });
   }
}
```

Hope this would work!!

Answer (score 1):

Tip: "From what I have read the form group must be declared in the constructor.", move it to OnInit

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a form control inside your form group to hold the reference to the file. Like this:

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
        summary: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        description: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        isurgent: [false],
        file: []
      });
```

And then when you assign the file:

```js
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.form.patchValue({ file: files.item(0) });
  }
```

Also, the suggestion to move the form group creation to `ngOnInit()` is valid, but will not solve your particular issue.

Currently, when you instantiate the form, you are mixing the form builder (`fb`) and instantiating the form controls yourself.
Inside a `fb.group({` call, values like `[]` is short hand to instantiate a new form control. So, to consistently use the form builder change the `summary` and `description` instantiations to this:

```js
summary: ['', [Validators.required]],
description: ['', [Validators.required]],
```

Comment: I am receiving the error 'files.item is not a function' with this solution

Comment: Yeah, I intentionally left it that way because it was part of your code and not related to the question. I was assuming you weren't passing the event directly but the `$event.target.files` as the parameter to `handleFileInput`. Someone else answered at the same time as me and had fixed that part too.